# Running a code multiple times and saving data after every run in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am running this code 10 times. After every run, I want to create a folder `n` where `n` is the number of the run and save the data with file name `Inv_Radius_220_47_53ND.csv` in that folder. For instance, after first run, folder `1` is created and then `Inv_Radius_220_47_53ND.csv` is saved. Then after second run, folder `2` is created and  `Inv_Radius_220_47_53ND.csv` is saved in this folder. Just for info, the file name should be the same across all folders, only different folder names.

```
def function():
    from scipy.stats import truncnorm
    import numpy as np
    import csv 

    a, b = 47.0,53.0
    Nodes=12  #reshape into
    r = (1e-6)*np.linspace(truncnorm.ppf(0.001, a, b),truncnorm.ppf(1.0, a, b), Nodes)
    print("r =",[r])

    sort_r = np.sort(r); 
    r1=sort_r[::-1]
    print("r1 =",[r1])
    #print("r =",[r])

    r1=r1.reshape(1,Nodes)
    print("r1 shape =",[r1])

    r2 = r.copy()

   
    np.random.shuffle(r2.ravel()[1:])
    print("r2 =",[r2])    

    r2=r2.reshape(1,Nodes)
    print("r2 =",[r2])                          #actual radius values in mu(m)

    maximum = r2.max()
    indice1 = np.where(r2 == maximum)
    # minimmum = r2.min()
    # indice2 = np.where(r2 == minimum)
    r2[indice1] = r2[0][0]
    r2[0][0] = maximum
    #print(r2)
    r2[0][Nodes-1] = maximum  #+0.01*maximum
    #print(r2)
    print("r2 with max at (0,0)=",[r2])

    with open('Inv_Radius_220_47_53ND.csv', 'w+') as f: 
        inv_r=1/r2
        print("inv_r =",[inv_r])
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(inv_r)
     

    mean=np.mean(r)
    print("Mean =",mean)
    var=np.var(r)
    print("var =",var)
    std=np.std(r)
    print("std =",std)

for x in range(10):
    function()
```

Comment: you already seem to be saving into a csv file. so is your question just how to create a folder and save the csv there?  You can use [os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) for that

Comment: Yes I want to know how to create folders and save the csv there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I truncated the parts that weren't important to the question but is this what you're looking for?

```
import os
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
import numpy as np
import csv


def function(run):
    ...

    # Create the folder with the number of the run as name
    # Add 1 to run so the first run is 1 and not 0
    parent_folder = str(run + 1)
    os.mkdir(parent_folder)
    # Join the parent folder with the filepath: 0/Inv_Radius_220_47_53ND.csv
    with open(os.path.join(parent_folder, 'Inv_Radius_220_47_53ND.csv'), 'w+') as f:
        inv_r = 1 / r2
        print("inv_r =", [inv_r])
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(inv_r)

    ...


for x in range(10):
    function(x)
```

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: Do you get a error?

Comment: Yes I do. ```line 93, in <module>
    function()

  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Sept13_2022\Automating\Test\Test.py", line 71, in function
    with open(os.path.join(parent_folder, 'Inv_Radius_220_47_53ND.csv'), 'w+') as f:

  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py", line 78, in join
    path = os.fspath(path)

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType```

Comment: @user19862793 My mistake, try again please